# Best way to format toString output to look good in a JList

Tags: string, string-formatting, jlist

I am overriding the toString method in a Java model object. I want to format the output so it lines up horizontally, consistently, in a JList.

I have no idea how to do this- I don't know how to do variable padding in java.lang.String.

String.format does not appear to be sufficient to do variable padding, but I could be wrong...

Can someone explain?

Comment: Take easy, The JList component will format your string, I just recommend to you do not use break lines in your strings.

Comment: I don't think the padding in a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) is created by the toString() method

Comment: I could probably just create a custom renderer for the JList